# Need a regex to match integer without leading 0s or blank string zero to 4 digits

Tags: regex, javafx

Need a regex (for javafx) to match integer without leading 0s or blank string zero to 4 digits.

Ex: `'1234'`, `'123'`, `'12'`, `'1'`, `''`

I tried `^[1-9][0-9]?{0,4}`, but it doesn't match a blank string.

Comment: Try [`^([1-9][0-9]{0,3})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/NXa25j/1).

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. Please provide some values that should match (and mark them as such), as well as some (also clearly marked) values that should **not** match.

Comment: What about `'0'`? Should it be matched?

Answer (score 4):

A pattern for a 4 digit number not starting with a zero and also matching an empty string is

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,3})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXa25j/1).

- `^` - start of string
- `([1-9][0-9]{0,3})?`  - an optional (1 or 0) sequences of

  - `[1-9]` - a digit from `1` to `9`
  - `[0-9]{0,3}` - any 0 to 3 digits
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Or if `0` should be matched: `^(?:|0|[1-9][0-9]{0,3})$`

Comment: @fabian In that case, I'd go for `^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,3})?$`. Also, in this case, a capturing group is not a big overhead, but adds to the readability IMHO (one of those rare cases when I am using a capturing group where I would be using a non-capturing one in many other cases). Also, some regex parsers do not like empty alternatives, I'd rather choose an optional group.

Answer (score -1):

`^[1-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?` covers all but the ''

Comment: it matches `01` which is what OP explicitly avoiding